# Excel - Pivot Slicer or Via VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, slicers, vba

I am posting this to all Excel Champs and Code Experts. I am familiar with Pivot and Slicer feature of excel however came with an requirement and I could not think of any way I can achieve it via pivot ( preferably )

The Requirement is like this. I  have team data in col 1 and Sales figures in col 2. Now with a simple pivot, I can have the team totals and things like that but I need to put in slicer on team name. If I select Team one , it should show Team one sales against total of other three team . PLease advice if there is a way to do that. In summary I need to compare a person's /team performance against total peers

Team    Sales
One 20000
Two     15000
Three   500
Four    35000
One 500

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow which is about asking **specific** and **answerable** **programming** related questions. This has nothing to do with a specific programming problem you are having. I would recommend that you try your luck on superuser.com however you will still need to ask something **specific** over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with formula next to your PivotTable values. You will use formula against your total range of values in `col2`. If your columns are set to range `A:B`, and PivotTable is in range `D:E`, then put this formula `=E2/(SUM($B$2:$B$30)-SUMIF($A$2:$A$30,D2,$B$2:$B$30))` in cell `F2`. You should get result as follows.

[image]

If you need to have result inside your PivotTable, then you should use PowerPivot and create a measure. try looking at this for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg399161(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Hi Kresimir, Thanks for responding . I appreciate and your solution is working however it clicked something similar and sharing in case if you feel it will come handy. I created another coloumn in my table called "Sale of Rest of team". In this col. I plotted - "Total Sale - Sales of the team in corresponding Row) . For eg for Team one , this means ( Total sales- Sales of Team 1).  From here on .. life was easy and back to normal !!. I just created a normal pivot with slicer on team name and it compared the team one again rest of the teams !!! Thanks again ..